# Inconsistency in RANSAC implementation from Scipy Cookbook

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

Recently I've checked the RANSAC implementation from the Cookbook: http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/RANSAC , but it doesn't seem to be consistent with the RANSAC algorithm itself.

Looking at the plot there, how can it be that some of data points, which are quite far from the best model (see points in the bottom), are considered as "RANSAC data", while some other points being closer to the model are not?

From my point of view It contradicts the main idea of the RANSAC algorithm where all points inside the pre-defined threshold area are considered as inliers.

**Why is it not so in this implementation and are there any other RANSAC implementations in Python?**

Thanks for your help!

Cheers,
Alexey

Answer (score 3):

No it does not contradict the idea of RANSAC. The plot is a little misleading though.

What is plotted as blue crosses are the sample points (`best_inlier_idxs` = `maybeinliers` + `alsoinliers`) of which some (exactly the points in `alsoinliers`, ie the consensus set) support the model (`maybemodel`) which was fitted to a random sample of the data (`maybeinliers`). Which means all points given by `alsoinliers` should indeed be closer to the `maybemodel` than the closest point not in support of it.

However, the `maybemodel` fit is **not** shown in the plot. What is shown is the `bettermodel` (blue line, "RANSAC fit") which is obtained by fitting model parameters to **all** points in `best_inlier_idxs` (not just the ones in `maybeinliers`).

Furthermore, `best_inlier_idxs` contains both `alsoinliers` and `maybeinliers`. There may well be points in the randomly chose sample `maybeinliers` that do in fact not support the `maybemodel` fit (i.e. they are not within a threshold away). These points are also shown as blue crosses even though they are farther away than other points not in the supporting set.

I modified the plotting a little to also indicate the best proposed model (`maybemodel`) and the random sample (`maybeinliers`) within the "RANSAC data". The important thing are the circles around some of the crosses which highlight the fact that the random samples are contained in the RANSAC data.

[image]

[image]

Here's the code for the modified plotting:

```
iterations = 0
bestfit = None
besterr = numpy.inf
best_inlier_idxs = None
while iterations < k:
    maybe_idxs, test_idxs = random_partition(n,data.shape[0])
    maybeinliers = data[maybe_idxs,:]
    test_points = data[test_idxs]
    maybemodel = model.fit(maybeinliers)
    test_err = model.get_error( test_points, maybemodel)
    also_idxs = test_idxs[test_err < t] # select indices of rows with accepted points
    alsoinliers = data[also_idxs,:]
    if debug:
        print 'test_err.min()',test_err.min()
        print 'test_err.max()',test_err.max()
        print 'numpy.mean(test_err)',numpy.mean(test_err)
        print 'iteration %d:len(alsoinliers) = %d'%(
            iterations,len(alsoinliers))
    if len(alsoinliers) > d:
        betterdata = numpy.concatenate( (maybeinliers, alsoinliers) )
        bettermodel = model.fit(betterdata)
        better_errs = model.get_error( betterdata, bettermodel)
        thiserr = numpy.mean( better_errs )
        if thiserr < besterr:
            bestfit = bettermodel
            besterr = thiserr
            best_inlier_idxs = numpy.concatenate( (maybe_idxs, also_idxs) )
    best_maybe_model = maybemodel
    best_random_set = maybe_idxs
    iterations+=1
if bestfit is None:
    raise ValueError("did not meet fit acceptance criteria")
if return_all:
    return bestfit, {'inliers':best_inlier_idxs, 'best_random_set':best_random_set,'best_maybe_model':best_maybe_model}
else:
    return bestfit

def test():
    # generate perfect input data

    n_samples = 500
    n_inputs = 1
    n_outputs = 1
    A_exact = 20*numpy.random.random((n_samples,n_inputs) )
    perfect_fit = 60*numpy.random.normal(size=(n_inputs,n_outputs) ) # the model
    B_exact = scipy.dot(A_exact,perfect_fit)
    assert B_exact.shape == (n_samples,n_outputs)

    # add a little gaussian noise (linear least squares alone should handle this well)
    A_noisy = A_exact + numpy.random.normal(size=A_exact.shape )
    B_noisy = B_exact + numpy.random.normal(size=B_exact.shape )

    if 1:
        # add some outliers
        n_outliers = 100
        all_idxs = numpy.arange( A_noisy.shape[0] )
        numpy.random.shuffle(all_idxs)
        outlier_idxs = all_idxs[:n_outliers]
        non_outlier_idxs = all_idxs[n_outliers:]
        A_noisy[outlier_idxs] =  20*numpy.random.random((n_outliers,n_inputs) )
        B_noisy[outlier_idxs] = 50*numpy.random.normal(size=(n_outliers,n_outputs) )

    # setup model

    all_data = numpy.hstack( (A_noisy,B_noisy) )
    input_columns = range(n_inputs) # the first columns of the array
    output_columns = [n_inputs+i for i in range(n_outputs)] # the last columns of the array
    debug = True
    model = LinearLeastSquaresModel(input_columns,output_columns,debug=debug)

    linear_fit,resids,rank,s = scipy.linalg.lstsq(all_data[:,input_columns],
                                                  all_data[:,output_columns])

    # run RANSAC algorithm
    ransac_fit, ransac_data = ransac(all_data,model,
                                     50, 1000, 7e3, 300, # misc. parameters
                                     debug=debug,return_all=True)
    if 1:
        import pylab

        sort_idxs = numpy.argsort(A_exact[:,0])
        A_col0_sorted = A_exact[sort_idxs] # maintain as rank-2 array

        if 1:
            pylab.plot( A_noisy[:,0], B_noisy[:,0], 'k.', label='data' )
            pylab.plot( A_noisy[ransac_data['inliers'],0], B_noisy[ransac_data['inliers'],0], 'bx', label='RANSAC data' )
        pylab.plot( A_noisy[ransac_data['best_random_set'],0], B_noisy[ransac_data['best_random_set'],0], 'ro', mfc='none',label='best random set (maybeinliers)' )
        else:
            pylab.plot( A_noisy[non_outlier_idxs,0], B_noisy[non_outlier_idxs,0], 'k.', label='noisy data' )
            pylab.plot( A_noisy[outlier_idxs,0], B_noisy[outlier_idxs,0], 'r.', label='outlier data' )
        pylab.plot( A_col0_sorted[:,0],
                    numpy.dot(A_col0_sorted,ransac_fit)[:,0],
                    label='RANSAC fit' )
        pylab.plot( A_col0_sorted[:,0],
                    numpy.dot(A_col0_sorted,perfect_fit)[:,0],
                    label='exact system' )
        pylab.plot( A_col0_sorted[:,0],
                    numpy.dot(A_col0_sorted,linear_fit)[:,0],
                    label='linear fit' )
        pylab.plot( A_col0_sorted[:,0],
                    numpy.dot(A_col0_sorted,ransac_data['best_maybe_model'])[:,0],
                    label='best proposed model (maybemodel)' )
        pylab.legend()
        pylab.show()

if __name__=='__main__':
    test()
```